# C++ Custom iterator class

Tags: c++, iterator

I want to implement a custom iterator class that has some differences with typical iterators. The container in this example is a vector and the idea is to walk throw it but using a specific syntax, like this:

```
int main()
{

    VectorElement E;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Element e;
        e.id = i;
        E.push_back(e);
    }

    for (ElementIterator e(E); e.end(); ++e)
        cout << "Element " << e.id << endl;

}
```

I tried with the following definitions, but it gives me a Segmentation Fault at the static_cast line after two iterations. Does someone know how to improve this? Thanks

```
class Element
{
public:

    Element() {};    
    size_t id;
};

typedef vector<Element> VectorElement;

class ElementIterator: public Element
{
    typedef vector<Element>::iterator iter;

public:

    ElementIterator(const Element& e) : Element(e) { }    
    ElementIterator(VectorElement& ve_)
    {
        ve = &ve_;
        it = ve->begin();
    }

    ElementIterator operator++()
    {
        ++it;
        *this = static_cast<ElementIterator>(*it);
        return *this;
    }

    bool end()
    {
        if (it != ve->end() )
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    vector<Element>* ve;
    iter it;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is alternate implementation that does not rely on global variables or deriving from 'Element':

```
class Element
{
public:

    Element() {};    
    size_t id;
};

class ElementIterator
{
    std::vector<Element>& ve;
    std::vector<Element>::iterator it;

public:   
    ElementIterator(std::vector<Element>& ve_) : ve(ve_)
    {    
        it = ve.begin();
    }

    ElementIterator(const ElementIterator &rhs) : ve(rhs.ve)
    {
        it = rhs.it;
    }

    ElementIterator operator++()
    {
        ++it;
        return *this;
    }

    const Element *operator ->() const
    {            
        assert(!this->end());

        return &(*it);
    }

    bool end() const
    {       
        if (it == ve.end())
            return true;

        return false;
    }
};
```

Main:

```
int main()
{    
    std::vector<Element> E;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Element e;
        e.id = i;
        E.push_back(e);
    }

    for (ElementIterator e(E); !e.end(); ++e)
        std::cout << "Element " << e->id << std::endl;
}
```

NOTE: I changed the behaviour of 'ElementIterator::end' so that it returns 'true' when it is at the end which seemed more logical.

Try it here:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8bf8b1025d87a882

Comment: Do you think is there a way to return a pure Element, a not a pointer? I am trying to use this in another scenario where I use the Element as a key for a map.

Comment: Yes, you can add a 'operator *' to return a reference instead. Not sure why I did not think of that myself :P.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the segfault occurs because the 'ElementIterator::operator++()' increments the internal 'it' attribute and then deferences it without verifying that its valid first. It could be implemented as follows:

```
ElementIterator::operator ++()
{
    ++it;
    if (!this->end())
        *this = static_cast<ElementIterator>(*it);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it surely improves the code, but the segfaults occurs in the second time the static_cast is called, although the vector has five elements.

Answer (score 0):

I finally use this workaround, that it is not elegant but works. The main problem was that the iterator "it" was overwritten so I put it in the global scope.

```
class Element
{
public:

    Element() {};    
    size_t id;
};

typedef vector<Element> VectorElement;
typedef vector<Element>::iterator iter;
iter it;

class ElementIterator: public Element
{


public:

    ElementIterator(const Element& e) : Element(e) { }    
    ElementIterator(VectorElement& ve_)
    {
        ve = &ve_;
        it = ve->begin();
    }

    ElementIterator operator++()
    {
        ++it;
        *this = static_cast<ElementIterator>(*it);
        return *this;
    }

    bool end()
    {
        if (it != ve->end() )
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    vector<Element>* ve;

};
```

Comment: Solving this with global variables seems less than ideal. Perhaps you might re-think how the iterator derives from 'Element' rather than storing that as an internal attribute.